# Add div above another div

Tags: jquery, html

```
<div>
  <div class="one">One</div>
  <div class="two">Two</div>
  <div class="three">Three</div>
  <div class="four">Four</div>
  <div class="five">Five</div>
</div>
```

I need to add a div between div Three and Four, but I can't use any sort of targeting on the parent div (only the divs inside it).

```
jQuery('.four').parent().prepend('<div class="addme">Add Me!</div>');
```

This as you probably know adds it to the top, above div One. Without the ".parent()" it adds the div inside of div Four, before the content. Same difference for ".append()".

Anyone got a solution?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) or [`.after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/) like this:

```
jQuery('.four').before('<div class="addme">Add Me!</div>');
//or...
jQuery('.three').after('<div class="addme">Add Me!</div>');
```

Comment: Pretty sure I googled this for 10minutes and never found .before or .after. I fail. Thank you kind sir.

Comment: @wish: no need to Google! [jQuery's API docs](http://api.jquery.com) are _really_ good; always check those out first.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
if (jQuery(window).width() > 770) {
    jQuery('#check-skiplinks').before('<div id="header-nav" class="skip-content"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml("topMenu") ?></div>');
} else if(jQuery(window).width()< 770) {
 jQuery('#check-skiplinks').after('<div id="header-nav" class="skip-content"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml("topMenu") ?></div>');
}
</script>

Hi, I need to perform like this action. but it won't work. Please suggest me some tips.

Comment: Thank you from me too.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.three').after('<div class="addme">Add Me!</div>');
```