# How do I insert a new div before the last div using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

```
<div id="one">test test</div>
<div id="two">test test</div>
<div id="three">test test</div>
<div id="four">test test</div>
<div id="five">test test</div>
```

If I want to insert a div dynamically with jQuery in between divs "four" and "five", how would I go about doing that?

I tried this but it didn't work:

`$("<div id='four-point-five'></div>").before("#five");`

Comment: Have a read through the API docs on DOM Insertion, starting here: http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add div above another div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3892739/add-div-above-another-div)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the other way around:

```
$("#five").before("<div id='four-point-five'></div>");
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it like that, you should use [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore);

```
$("<div id='four-point-five'></div>").insertBefore("#five");
```

Alternately, you can swop the elements around;

```
$("#five").before("<div id='four-point-five'></div>");
```

If you are after a generic solution, you might find the [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector) or [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector) selector interesting (depending on the rest of your HTML)

```
$('div:last').before("<div id='four-point-five'></div>");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#five").before("<div id='four-point-five'></div>")
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("<div id='four-point-five'></div>").insertAfter("#four");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("<div id='four-point-five'></div>").insertBefore("#five");

// OR

$("#five").before("<div id='four-point-five'></div>");
```

The problem is that <s>you didn't read the doco</s> the [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) method expects the existing element as the `$()` selector and the new content as the parameter. The [`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) method works the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
>  $("#five").before( " <div id='four-point-five'> </div> " );
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
$("#five").before("<div id='four-point-five'></div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/gNQwR/

```
$("<div>").attr('id', 'four-point-five').text('test 4.5').insertBefore("#five");
```

Comment: You may find [`jQuery(html, props)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) interesting.

Comment: Ha... indeed. I always thought that this was the "correct" way of doing it.  Thanks for the pointing this out!